# macOS - Use `Process` to telnet to an IP address and pass commands

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, telnet

I'm developing a macOS app where I need to connect using `telnet` to a device and send commands to it.

(BTW, I'm connecting to a Roku)

This is as far as I got

```
func telnet(to host: String, port: String) {
    let process = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()

    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/telnet")
    process.arguments = [host, port]
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    do {
        try process.run()
    } catch {
        return
    }

    let resultData = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let result = String (data: resultData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    print(result)
}

telnet(to: "10.0.1.11", port: "8080")
```

The problem is that the Process is closed immediately. I need to leave the Process open and somehow send commands to the device and then close the connection.

So those are my questions:

1. How can I leave the Process running?
2. How can I send commands to the device through the telnet connection?

Comment: You probably need to set up the standardInput and standardError descriptors as well.

Comment: @DavidBerry `standardInput` seems to be exactly what I need, do you have any examples on how to use it? I can't find anything online.

Comment: You'll want to create a pipe for it as well.  You'll write into one pipe (standardInput) to send data to the child program and read data from a second pipe (standardOutput) to read data from the child.  But, as indicated by @duskwuff, you're best bet is probably just to avoid telnet completely unless there's a good reason to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet will be to avoid using `Process` and make a network connection directly from your application. (This will also free you from your dependency on `/usr/local/bin/telnet`, which is not present in a clean install of macOS.)

The [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) pod looks like an excellent way of doing this. The "Client socket example" in the documentation appears to cover most of your questions.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. I already had the [BlueSocket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket) module in my project, so that's what I ended up using.